# Why can't I install opendkim-2.9.0 on my VPS?

Tags: server, 13.10, vps, mail-server

This is the output I get:

```
-checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c    
-checking whether build environment is sane... yes    
-checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p    
-checking for gawk... gawk    
-checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes    
-checking whether make supports nested variables... yes    
-checking for gcc... gcc    
-checking whether the C compiler works... yes    
-checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out    
-checking for suffix of executables...     
-checking whether we are cross compiling... no    
-checking for suffix of object files... o    
-checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes    
-checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes    
-checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed    
-checking for style of include used by make... GNU    
-checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3    
-checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99    
-checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 and cc understand -c and -o together... yes    
-checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu    
-checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu    
-checking how to print strings... printf    
-checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed   
-checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep    
-checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E    
-checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F    
-checking for ld used by gcc -std=gnu99... /usr/bin/ld    
-checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes    
-checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B    
-checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm    
-checking whether ln -s works... yes    
-checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080    
-checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes    
-checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes    
-checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop   
-checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop    
-checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r    
-checking for objdump... objdump    
-checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all    
-checking for dlltool... no    
-checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n    
-checking for ar... ar    
-checking for archiver @FILE support... @    
-checking for strip... strip    
-checking for ranlib... ranlib    
-checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc -std=gnu99 object... ok    
-checking for sysroot... no    
-checking for mt... mt    
-checking if mt is a manifest tool... no    
-checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E    
-checking for ANSI C header files... yes    
-checking for sys/types.h... yes    
-checking for sys/stat.h... yes    
-checking for stdlib.h... yes    
-checking for string.h... yes    
-checking for memory.h... yes    
-checking for strings.h... yes    
-checking for inttypes.h... yes    
-checking for stdint.h... yes    
-checking for unistd.h... yes    
-checking for dlfcn.h... yes    
-checking for objdir... .libs    
-checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no    
-checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC    
-checking if gcc -std=gnu99 PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes    
-checking if gcc -std=gnu99 static flag -static works... yes    
-checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... yes    
-checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes    
-checking whether the gcc -std=gnu99 linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes    
-checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
-checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so    
-checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate    
-checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes    
-checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes    
-checking whether to build shared libraries... yes    
-checking whether to build static libraries... yes    
-checking for pkg-config... no    
-checking for the pthreads library -lpthreads... no    
-checking whether pthreads work without any flags... no    
-checking whether pthreads work with -Kthread... no    
-checking whether pthreads work with -kthread... no    
-checking for the pthreads library -llthread... no    
-checking whether pthreads work with -pthread... yes    
-checking for joinable pthread attribute... PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE    
-checking if more special flags are required for pthreads... no    
-checking for library containing inet_addr... none required    
-checking for library containing dlopen... -ldl    
-checking for library containing socket... none required
-checking for library containing inet_aton... none required    
-checking for library containing inet_pton... none required   
-checking for library containing inet_ntop... none required    
-checking for library containing getaddrinfo... none required    
-checking for library containing res_ninit... no    
-checking for library containing res_sertservers... no    
-checking for library containing getopt_long... none required    
-checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes    
-checking for netinet/in.h... yes    
-checking for arpa/nameser.h... yes    
-checking for netdb.h... yes    
-checking for resolv.h... yes    
-checking for useconds_t... yes    
-checking whether the resolver works without -lresolv... no    
-checking whether the resolver works with -lresolv... yes    
-checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes    
-checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes    
-checking for arpa/inet.h... yes    
-checking fcntl.h usability... yes    
-checking fcntl.h presence... yes    
-checking for fcntl.h... yes    
-checking limits.h usability... yes    
-checking limits.h presence... yes    
-checking for limits.h... yes    
-checking iso/limits_iso.h usability... no   
-checking iso/limits_iso.h presence... no    
-checking for iso/limits_iso.h... no    
-checking for netdb.h... (cached) yes    
-checking for netinet/in.h... (cached) yes    
-checking paths.h usability... yes    
-checking paths.h presence... yes    
-checking for paths.h... yes
-checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes    
-checking for string.h... (cached) yes    
-checking sys/file.h usability... yes    
-checking sys/file.h presence... yes    
-checking for sys/file.h... yes    
-checking sys/param.h usability... yes    
-checking sys/param.h presence... yes    
-checking for sys/param.h... yes    
-checking sys/socket.h usability... yes    
-checking sys/socket.h presence... yes    
-checking for sys/socket.h... yes    
-checking sys/time.h usability... yes    
-checking sys/time.h presence... yes    
-checking for sys/time.h... yes    
-checking syslog.h usability... yes    
-checking syslog.h presence... yes    
-checking for syslog.h... yes    
-checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes    
-checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes    
-checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes    
-checking for _Bool... yes    
-checking for uid_t in sys/types.h... yes    
-checking for mode_t... yes    
-checking for off_t... yes    
-checking for pid_t... yes    
-checking for size_t... yes    
-checking for ssize_t... yes    
-checking for uint16_t... yes    
-checking for uint32_t... yes    
-checking for uint64_t... yes    
-checking vfork.h usability... no    
-checking vfork.h presence... no    
-checking for vfork.h... no    
-checking for fork... yes    
-checking for vfork... yes 
-checking for working fork... yes
-checking for working vfork... (cached) yes    
-checking type of array argument to getgroups... gid_t    
-checking for getgroups... yes    
-checking for working getgroups... yes    
-checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes    
-checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes    
-checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes    
-checking for sys/time.h... (cached) yes    
-checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes    
-checking for alarm... yes    
-checking for working mktime... yes    
-checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes    
-checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... yes    
-checking for dup2... yes    
-checking for endpwent... yes    
-checking for getcwd... yes    
-checking for gethostname... yes    
-checking for gethostbyname... yes    
-checking for getaddrinfo... yes    
-checking for gethostbyname2... yes    
-checking for gettimeofday... yes    
-checking for isascii... yes    
-checking for memchr... yes    
-checking for memmove... yes    
-checking for memset... yes    
-checking for regcomp... yes    
-checking for select... yes    
-checking for socket... yes    
-checking for strcasecmp... yes    
-checking for strchr... yes    
-checking for strdup... yes    
-checking for strerror... yes    
-checking for strncasecmp... yes    
-checking for strrchr... yes    
-checking for strstr... yes    
-checking for strtol... yes    
-checking for strtoul... yes    
-checking for strtoull... yes    
-checking for realpath... yes    
-checking for strsep... yes
-checking bsd/string.h usability... no    
-checking bsd/string.h presence... no    
-checking for bsd/string.h... no    
-checking for strlcat... no    
-checking for library containing strlcat... no    
-checking for library containing strlcpy... no    
-checking for strlcpy... no    
-checking for library containing strlcat... (cached) no    
-checking for library containing strlcpy... (cached) no    
-checking strl.h usability... no    
-checking strl.h presence... no    
-checking for strl.h... no    
-checking for strl.h in /usr/local/include/strl... checking for strl.h in /usr/include/strl... no    
-checking for struct sockaddr_un.sun_len... no    
-checking for struct sockaddr_in.sin_len... no    
-checking for struct sockaddr_in6.sin6_len... no    
-checking for rrdtool... no    
-checking for sendmail... /usr/sbin/sendmail    
-checking for OpenSSL includes... no    
-checking for OpenSSL library and includes... /usr/pkg    
-checking for milter library and includes…
configure: error: milter not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have libbsd-dev installed, that fixed it for me.

You can read about this in the release notes:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/opendkim/files/RELEASE_NOTES/view

BUILD: Add checks for strlcat()/strlcpy() in libbsd.  Patch from
        Scott Kitterman.